# Graph with distance and travelling times: find most km's in 24 hours (with constraints)

Tags: python, algorithm, mathematical-optimization

In two weeks, I'll be partaking in a contest where people have to travel the most kilometers by train in The Netherlands. Everyone has 24 hours to travel, and the person with the longest distance travelled wins. However, you can only travel along each 'section' once. For example, if you travel from Rotterdam to Amsterdam and back from Amsterdam to The Hague, a big part will not count since you've already been there. If you come along the same section twice, your kilometers will not count. To get the optimal itinerary, I want to use the power of algorithms :).

In order to find the best route, I decided to use Python and use the `networkx` package to get a visualisation of the Dutch railways. So far so good, but now comes the fun part: the algorithm. Given a graph with all railway sections and distances, how can you solve the problem? Here is the graph, without distances.

[image]

It seems to me like this is a combination of the Travelling Salesman Problem (except you can visit cities multiple times), a Maximum Flow optimization, and some kind of inverted Dijkstra algorithm :p. Is there an existing algorithm that can solve this? Or will I need to construct something myself? If the latter, is something like backtracking a good approach?

Comment: *If* you couldn't visit a city more than once, then you would have the Longest Path problem, which (unlike Shortest Path) is NP-hard. But in any case I think you need to focus on the timetable: minimising waiting times. Also are some trains faster than others? Obviously those you want to include them if possible.

Comment: I think what @j_random_hacker said is a pretty decent idea. Assuming all trains run at the same speed, you want to minimize the time spent not traveling, and you could model all available connections within the 24 hour window as vertices. Then add an edge `(u,v)` of weight `c` iff connection `u` arrives at station `X` at time `T` and connection `v` leaves at station `X` at time `T + c`. Add a start vertex `s` and edges `(s,v)` of weight `0` for all `v`, and a target vertex `t` with edge `(v,t)` of weight `24 - v.arrival_time`. Now find a shortest path. (cont)

Comment: The don't-count-stuff-twice condition would be pretty hard to encode; you could of course just create copies of the graph of remaining connections to model branching, basically, and encode it in there, but that might blow up considerably.

Comment: @G.Bach one way to deal with "don't count stuff twice" is to formulate this as a mixed integer programming problem instead of using a graph, because then you can use constraints to not count something more than once. I've coded it up in my solution using the pulp package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing to note is that classical graph-based algorithms like longest path won't really apply here because of the time table, so I would frame this as a mixed integer linear programming problem. You would define two types of variables:

1. Binary variables `x_t` for whether a given train trip `t` (identified by source `c1`, destination `c2`, start time `t1`, and end time `t2`) are used.
2. Binary variables `y_s` for whether a given segment `s` (identified by source `c1` and destination `c2`) is used (either once or multiple times) during the day.

The objective of the optimization problem is to maximize the sum of segment distances `d_s` times the indicator for whether that segment is used `y_s` across all segments `s`. Because the segment indicator never exceeds 1 (even if we used it many times), this handles the "double counting segments" concern.

The first type of constraints you need ensure that we actually take a valid trip. For any given train trip `t` from source `c1` starting at time `t1`, the trip can be taken (`x_t = 1`) only if the number of prior trips into `c1` minus the number of prior trips out of `c1` is equal to 1. This ensures that we are actually at `c1` when we take a train from `c1` to somewhere else. If the set of all prior train trips into `c1` is `i1, i2, ..., in` and the set of all prior train trips out of `c1` is `o1, o2, ..., om`, then this constraint is `x_t <= x_i1 + x_i2 + ... + x_in - x_o1 - x_o2 - ... - x_om`. Note that this creates a tricky situation because we won't have a trip into the starting city of the entire itinerary. Therefore we'll create a fake starting city `S` and trips (of distance 0) from `S` to each other city at a time before all the other trips. If we call the trips from `S` to each other city `s1, s2, ..., sn`, then we'll add constraint `x_s1 + x_s2 + ... + x_sn = 1` so we have a single starting city for our itinerary.

The other constraints we need ensure that the `y_s` variables are set properly. In particular, we need to ensure `y_s` is set to 0 if none of the trips `t1, t2, ..., t_n` that use segment `s` are used throughout the day. This can be accomplished with `y_s <= x_t1 + x_t2 + ... + x_tn`.

You can implement this in a surprisingly readable and straightforward way with the pulp package in Python. I'll use `dists` to indicate segments and their lengths and `trains` to indicate all trains (tuples with start location, end location, start time, end time). By inspection, for this network we would expect just to go D to E for distance 3:

```
import pulp

dist = {("A", "B"): 1.0,
        ("B", "C"): 1.0,
        ("D", "E"): 3.0}
trains = [("A", "B", 1.0, 2.0),
          ("B", "C", 2.0, 3.0),
          ("C", "B", 3.5, 4.5),
          ("B", "A", 4.5, 5.5),
          ("D", "E", 1.0, 5.5)]
sources = set(list([t[0] for t in trains]))

x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", trains, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", dist.keys(), lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
s = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("s", sources, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat=pulp.LpInteger)
mod = pulp.LpProblem("Train Optimization", pulp.LpMaximize)

# Objective
mod += sum([dist[k] * y[k] for k in dist])

# Feasibility
for t in trains:
    mod += x[t] <= s[t[0]] + sum([x[k] for k in trains if k[1] == t[0] and k[3] <= t[2]]) - sum([x[k] for k in trains if k != t and k[0] == t[0] and k[2] <= t[2]])
mod += sum([s[k] for k in sources]) == 1

# Valid y variables
for k in dist:
    mod += y[k] <= sum([x[t] for t in trains if (t[0] == k[0] and t[1] == k[1]) or (t[1] == k[0] and t[0] == k[1])])

# Solve
mod.solve()
for t in trains:
    print "Trip", t, "used:", x[t].value()
```

As expected, we get:

```
Trip ('A', 'B', 1.0, 2.0) used: 0.0
Trip ('B', 'C', 2.0, 3.0) used: 0.0
Trip ('C', 'B', 3.5, 4.5) used: 0.0
Trip ('B', 'A', 4.5, 5.5) used: 0.0
Trip ('D', 'E', 1.0, 5.5) used: 1.0
```

We could double the distances for A-B and B-C:

```
dist = {("A", "B"): 2.0,
        ("B", "C"): 2.0,
        ("D", "E"): 3.0}
```

And now, as expected, we start taking the A-B-C loop (whether we take the C-B and B-A return trips doesn't affect the objective so the optimization engine can decide either way whether to take them):

```
Trip ('A', 'B', 1.0, 2.0) used: 1.0
Trip ('B', 'C', 2.0, 3.0) used: 1.0
Trip ('C', 'B', 3.5, 4.5) used: 1.0
Trip ('B', 'A', 4.5, 5.5) used: 0.0
Trip ('D', 'E', 1.0, 5.5) used: 0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should model a directed graph with all departure-arrival travelling edges and also all waiting edges (between arrivals and departures of a station) for 24 hours. unfortunately your mileage bonus is not an attribute of an edge but depending on past edges as well. I doubt there is a very good algorithm to effectively find promising paths and shortcut bad ones. You could only drop paths with the same (or a subset of) travel segments and later arrival.

EDIT:

Depending on the rules you may also have to model Stations in Germany and Belgium for starting/stopping segments (counting the part from the border) or for fast transit. Also you may have to model departures on the previous day that arrive early in the morning and late evening departures that arrive the next day (counting the part of the segment that was within the day).

Comment: Woah, that's gonna be a lot of work :) Luckily, the trains have quite a regular schedule. I'll look into this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @LaurensJansma: It will. Keep us posted whether it worked out and how you did in the competition :-)